# java jar j2se app socket and memory clustering

Tags: java, memory, cluster-computing, shared

I am working on a chat server and it works fine, but i want to have the socket connections distributed.

how do i share my jar file, that is running as socket server
across many servers, sharing the memory and what's the best way to update one node
code without interruptions?